# Identifying a given set with the set of maximal ideals of polynomial ring containing given subset.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $F$ be a field (not necessarilly algebraically closed). Let $R=F[x_1,...,x_n]$ be the corresponding polynomial ring for variables $x_1,...,x_n$. Let $S$ be a subset of $R$.

We define $\mathcal{V}(S)=\lbrace \textbf{u} \in F^n : f(\textbf{u})= 0 \forall f \in S\rbrace$.

Also define the map $\mu(\textbf{u})= <x_1-u_1,...,x_n-u_n>$.

Can we identify the set $\mu(\mathcal{V}(S))$ (where we define this set to be the image of $\mathcal{V}(S)$ by $\mu$) with the set of maximal ideals of $R$ containing $S$? I'm okay with showing that anything in this set is such an ideal. But is the converse true? If this is not true, how would you describe $\mu(\mathcal{V}(S))$? Maybe geometrically?

Comment: Do you mean to assume $F$ is algebraically closed?  If not, there are maximal ideals of $R$ that are not even in the image of $\mu$ at all.

Comment: Please: how are $\;\mathcal V(S)\;,\;\;\mu(u)\;$ defined, again? It seems to be something is lacking in the first one, and in the second one: what map is that? Is that some inner product?

Comment: @Joanpemo: I think a "0" is missed after the equal sign, in the definition of $V(S)$. $\mu(u)$ is defined as an ideal generated by $x_1-u_1,\dots, x_n-u_n$. Not sure what $\mu(V(S))$ means though.

Comment: $\mu$ is a map from $F^n$ to the set of maximal ideals of $R$ and hence $\mu(\mathcal V(S))$ is just the image of $\mathcal V(S)$ w.r.t. the function $\mu$.

Comment: I have edited the question to answer all of these very justified questions, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field is algebraically closed, the statement is true due to Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Let $\mathfrak m \supset S$ be a maximal ideal of $R$. By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, we have $\mathfrak m = \langle x_1-u_1, \dotsc, x_n-u_n \rangle$ for some $u_i \in F$. Let $u=(u_1, \dotsc, u_n)$.

$\mathfrak m \supset S$ implies $\{u\} = \mathcal V(\mathfrak m) \subset \mathcal V(S)$, i.e.

$$\mathfrak m = \mu(u) \in \mu(\mathcal V(S)).$$

This is precisely the converse direction, you were lacking.

If the field is not algebraically closed, take an irreducible polynomial $f \in F[x_1]$ of degree $\geq 2$ and consider the maximal ideal

$$\mathfrak m = \langle f,x_2,x_3, \dotsc, x_n \rangle \subset F[x_1, \dotsc, x_n].$$

Clearly $\mathfrak m$ is not contained in $\mu(\mathcal V(\emptyset))$, but $\mathcal m$ is a maximal ideal containing $\emptyset$. (If you dont like the emptyset, take $S$ to be any subset of $\mathfrak m$)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I now see that my intuition wasn't right, how would you describe the image set? I can't picture it, which is my problem... Would there be a geometric picture for it?

Comment: The image set is just the set of all maximal ideals, that contain $S$ **and** are of the form $\langle x_1-u_1, \dotsc, x_n-u_n \rangle$. Geometrically, this is the set $\mathcal V(S)$.

Comment: Is the image of V(S) V(S) itself ?? I'm confused